# Problems with offset in overflow Div

Tags: jquery, css, html, offset

I'm having problems with JQuery Offset when used inside of a div that has a fixed height and overflow.

Inside this div I have two columns, a main and a sidebar.  I want one of the divs in the side bar to scroll within the div until it reaches the top, but then I want it to stay there.

I have a demo set up here : http://jsfiddle.net/zsJAr/53/

The div does scroll up but it doesn't start to stay at the top until it's scrolled past the top of the div, effectively cutting off the top part of the div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You needed the top offset where the `<h1>` is:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qaVnY/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // move the share this widget with the window
    if ($('#scrollingContent').length > 0) {
        var $widget = $("#scrollingContent");
        var $window = $("#overFlowDiv");
        var $topOffset = $('h1').height();
        var $offset = $widget.offset();
        var $initialMargin = $widget.css('marginTop');

        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > ($offset.top)) {
                $widget.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: ($window.scrollTop() - ($offset.top - $topOffset))
                });
            } else {
                $widget.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $initialMargin
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Mmmm, that seems to cut the #scrollingContent div even more so.

Comment: @Mouseman, refresh the fiddle, i had a little error, its fixed now

Comment: the fiddle was just an example, and not the actual page I have it on.  The entire page in question loads in an iframe with the top of the page having a menu and the rest of the page is the overflow div (keeping the menu at the top of the iframe)

I had solved my problem original by just subtracting the 'topoffset' with the height of the menu. Which I see is what you have done in your example.

I just thought I was 'hacking' it by doing it that way, as the script works in a regular window.  It just doesn't seem to function properly in that overflow'd div.

But it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

A little less conventional, but this seemed to work for me...

```
$window.scroll(function() {
if ($window.scrollTop() > $offset.top) {
$widget.stop().animate({
  marginTop: ($window.scrollTop() -(180 - $offset.top))
});
```